# FeedMe - Migrating a Feed to another environment

Tags: plugin-feedme

I have a feed setup and tested locally. Now, I'd like to roll it out to staging and production but there doesn't seem to be a way to export/import feeds so I need to setup the feeds manually on each environment. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything. Feeds in Feed Me are content rather than config, much like entries in channels and structures. However, unlike entries, there isn't an option to export a feed to allow easy migration from one environment to another.

I've always done this manually with one tab on the left showing my source environment with the feed set up, and another tab on the right with the target environmen. Then it's largely a tab-switching exercise to set up the feed on the target environment using the source environment as a reference.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad. Maybe a solution is on the road map.